# Fetch POST not working in Edge v42+

Tags: javascript, post, fetch

I know I'll lose most of you after this, but this error is occurring only in the most recent version of MS Edge, 42.17134.1.0.  At least some older versions that we have work fine (including 41.x)

I'm simply using the Fetch API to post login credentials to the server, but the call is never even made.  Edge just skips the call entirely.

It doesn't seem to be a Fetch issue because I tried jQuery and $post and that behaves exactly the same.  This is the code, with fake credentials of course.  You will note on every other browser (even IE) it returns the appropriate error of bad username/password.

```
document.getElementById("basicFetchButton").addEventListener("click", function(){
  return fetch('http://fldvd-apinet01.ad.nova.edu/appcentral/appcentral/auth/token', {
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    },
    body: 'grant_type=password&client_id=appcentral&username=user&password=test',
    method: 'POST'
  }).then((data) => {
    if (data.ok) {
      return data.json();
    }
    return data.json()
      .then((err) => {
        throw err;
      });
  });
});
```

Here is a link to a [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dnq2osoy/2218/)

Any thoughts or suggestions will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: When you say it fails, what is the error that you receive? Is it a backend error that you're generating or one specific to `fetch` and/or `ajax`?

Comment: Again, it just seems to skip the call entirely.  There is no error at all and no network call made in the network tab of the dev console.

Comment: Did you ever find the cause or solution to this @sn3ll? It seems to be working for me in later versions (44) but I have users still on 42 that are hitting this.

Comment: Nope, even posted a ticket on the edge developers board, never got a response.  We're Just advising users to upgrade to latest.  Typical Microsoft

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, I am late to the party. While making a site backward compatible with Edge 41 (EdgeHTML 16) and Safari 10, we ran upon an issue with the native Edge version of `fetch`.

Our issue was that cookies were present on the site and matched what was stored on the server, yet during our `fetch` request some cookies were not transmitted. This was a headache. Not quite the same as your issue, but the solution might help you.

The short of it is that installed a `fetch` polyfill (Source of [polyfill](https://unpkg.com/unfetch@4.1.0/polyfill/index.js)) plus modified the conditions upon when the polyfill is to execute.

Reading here brought me to my idea [GitHub](https://github.com/github/fetch/issues/407). *dgraham* recommended to wrap a polyfill for `fetch` in
`if (self.fetch && self.Headers.prototype.entries) {`

Well this doesn't work for me, because my goal is to load the polyfill only when
    1) `self.fetch` does not exist.
    2) `self.fetch' does exist yet it is Edge's EdgeHTML version.

How do we tell that `self.fetch` is present yet the user is viewing with a version of EdgeHTML? What I found was that Edge version 41.16299 - 44.18362 (most newer EdgeHTML versions) execute `!!self.Headers.prototype.entries.prototype` as `true`. This was tested on Edge versions 40, 41, 42, 44 using either BrowserStack.com or a VM Win10 machine.

Most other browsers execute the test as `false`. Here is the list of browsers that execute false to this test:

- Chrome v42
- Chrome v79
- FF v44
- FF v73
- Safari v10.1
- Safari v13.0

Back to the GitHub post from *dgraham*. Some browsers do have native code for `fetch` and `Headers`, yet test false for `!!self.Headers.prototype.entries`. Thus *dgraham* is correct that we need to test for this. The list of browsers that I found tested `false` when `!!self.Headers.prototype.entries` is executed is:

- Edge v40 (EdgeHTML 15.15063)
- FF v40

Sorry to be so long-winded. Here is the code that I wrapped the `fetch` polyfill within:

```
var loadPoly = false
if(!self.fetch){loadPoly = true}
if(!loadPoly && !self.Headers.prototype.entries){loadPoly = true}
if(!loadPoly && !!self.Headers.prototype.entries.prototype){loadPoly = true}
if(!!loadPoly){...
```